# Should I use Schema.org location tagging on every page?

Tags: seo, page, schema.org

I have a nicely tagged section on my homepage describing a restaurant’s location, city, state, zip, telephone, cuisine type, price and payments accepted.

Should I tag any of this info on every other of my pages, or is the home page the generally accepted place for this information?

I do include the address and phone number in the footer on every page, if this helps.

Comment: Are you duplicating the same information on multiple pages, or information for different locations on different pages? If the former, I'd avoid that sort of duplication as far as possible. Regarding the microdata, mark up all instances - there's no "generally accepted place" for it to go.

Comment: It's duplication on different pages (the site is for a restaurant, tho there is a page about a product inside that restaurant that may be worth tagging).  The reason I asked is because I was thinking about different pages showing up in search results, even tho the site is for one location only.

Comment: Without seeing it, hard to say catagorically, but I'd generally be inclined to avoid putting the same info on multiple pages. Depends how much we're talking about. Probably getting beyond scope of your original question here, though, but in any case: applying microdata to the same information on different pages is probably besides the point: it's the duplication of information itself that (might be) the issue.

Comment: The only duplication in this case is the restaurant name address and phone number in the footer of each page.  Just wondering if I should tag these on every page or just the index page where I've given even more detailed info about the business.

Comment: It'd be perfectly valid to do it for the footer info, and personally I would, for the sake of completeness. While microdata isn't doing much more than power Rich Snippets right now, it'll grow in the future, so I'd use it wherever you can (or at least structure your code in such a way that you _can_ add it without difficulty later on).

Comment: GDav, I'd love to give you credit here, wanna answer this?

Comment: That's very kind of you. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd be perfectly valid to mark up the same content in multiple locations. The point of microdata is that it makes your information understandable to machines (search engines, browsers, applications, what have you), so wherever data occurs on your site that you *can* mark up with microdata, you should mark it up.

Generally speaking, I would recommend using as much microdata as you can. While it isn't doing much more than power Rich Snippets right now, its applications will grow in the future. At the very least, it's worth structuring your code in such a way that you can add it later on.

The only thing I'd be careful of is the duplication of information itself. Small amounts of standard "boilerplate" information like an address and phone number should be fine, but anything more substantial that should be carefully considered. If you're feeling the need to reproduce large amounts of information across multiple pages, there's probably some scope to improve the site's architecture.

Answer (score 3):

Source: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1211158

> Google currently supports rich snippets for people, events, reviews,
>   products, recipes, and breadcrumb navigation.

So, no address information will be shown in SERP. However, Google may change it's algorithms some time later, like showing pin icon or anything else. And if you do not add your location to every page, just home page will have such icon (or whatever else).

> However, marking up as much content as possible helps search engines
>   better understand your content and present it in the most useful way.

Use [Snippet tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) to figure out what information google retrieves from your pages.

For your site I recommend you to implement:

- *events* schema in news if you have discounts
- *reviews* schema if you have testimonials page
- *breadcrumb navigation* schema for increasing your chances for receiving Popular sitelinks

Have good SERP results!

Comment: I've been wondering what I've left out to get sitelinks...I'll look into breadcrumbs!

Comment: Worth noting, while the address info doesn't result in a Rich Snippet, it does support local results: http://maps.google.com/help/maps/richsnippetslocal/